# IE11 Ajax Request will fail intermittently

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11

I am having weird issue in IE 11 (Version: 11.285.17134.0). After I logged in to my site I have been redirected to a landing page where the user performs a search which makes a `$.ajax` POST request to fill data in a grid.

However for every first request on that page it does not reach the server and the below error comes up.

> SCRIPT7002 : XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0007

After that every `$.ajax` post request works very well without issues. We are using common `$.ajax` function to perform post request.

```js
this.ajaxPost = function(webURL, dataType, dataParam, successFunc, errorFunc, asynchParam) {
  if (!asynchParam) {
    asynchParam = false
  }

  return $.ajax({
    async: asynchParam,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    url: webURL,
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataParam)
  }).done(successFunc).fail(errorFunc);
}
```

It looks like intermittent AJAX requests fail in IE 11. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aside from the issue, but `async` should always be set to `true`. Synchronous requests are incredibly bad practice.

Comment: yeah i understand that; it just a option i put if requires we can use it for synchronous request. Any comment regarding the main issue ?